# Desktop Outlook API to launch local file system browser

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, email-attachments

I’m developing a Microsoft Outlook Desktop add-in that saves attachments to the local file system. I can use SaveAsFile to save to a specific path, but is there a way to launch a file system dialog to browse to help the user figure out what path to save to?

Trying to do this in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0